# Delete bulk TJob Ids from _Job system data extension in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Kindly, let me know to delete a bulk tracking job records from _Job system data extension in marketing cloud or if possible using REST API in SSJS/Ampscript please share the code?

Thanks,
Manjesh

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*, and please be aware that requests for code to be provided are often not received well on this site.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't delete records from the _Job Data View. It's a system view that reflects what's been sent. Have you sent something silly you're regretting? It's probably better to just come clean, face the music and let some adults tidy up the mess.

Comment: we can delete the tracking job data manually and here is the link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_delete_tracking_job.htm&type=5 and checking for options on how to do it through automations/ssjs/ampscript activities.

Comment: That'd probably hide it, if they're aren't too many complaints. But to your question, no, there's not way to delete records from _Job. The view reflects what's been sent, rather than what you want to see.